# 光学ドライブの正確なタイプを取得する方法

Tags: c++, windows

Windows APIを使用して、特定の光学ドライブが"CDドライブ"なのか、"DVDドライブ"なのか"Blu-rayドライブ"なのかを取得する方法を探しています。
win32 の GetDriveType 関数では、光学ドライブを全て DRIVE_CDROM として認識してしまうため、要求に合いません。
DeviceIoControl などを使用して、デバイスを直接開いて取得する方法があるように予想しますが、なにを取得して判定するのがよいのか、見つけることができません。
参考となりそうなWebサイト、書籍、リファレンス、ソースコードなどがどこかにありましたら、お教えいただけると幸いです。

Comment: 言語は違いますが、この記事あたりでしょうか。[c＃ – 光学式ドライブ（ディスクではない）がCDドライブかDVDドライブかをどうやって確認できますか？](https://codeday.me/jp/qa/20190429/731474.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCSI Multimedia Commandの`GET CONFIGURATION`を呼ぶようです。具体的には[`IOCTL_CDROM_GET_CONFIGURATION`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddcdrm/ni-ntddcdrm-ioctl_cdrom_get_configuration)で[`GET_CONFIGURATION_HEADER`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddmmc/ns-ntddmmc-_get_configuration_header)を得るとその中に[`FEATURE_HEADER`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddmmc/ns-ntddmmc-_feature_header)が含まれており、更にその中に`FeatureCode`がありますが、これが[`FEATURE_NUMBER`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddmmc/ne-ntddmmc-_feature_number)としてドライブが持つ機能を表しています。これでドライブが`FeatureBDWrite`に対応しているかなどを調べることができそうです。

---

kunifさんのコメントにもありますが、Windows XP以降はExplorerからCD/DVDの書き込みに対応していますが、その内部機能は[Image Mastering API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/imapi/portal)として公開されています。もちろんC++言語からも呼び出し可能ですが、COM関連の本質的でない部分の記述が煩雑になるため、C#言語でのサンプルを書いてみました。

```
using System;
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        dynamic master = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("IMAPI2.MsftDiscMaster2"));
        foreach (string uniqueId in master) {
            dynamic recorder = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("IMAPI2.MsftDiscRecorder2"));
            recorder.InitializeDiscRecorder(uniqueId);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:", recorder.VolumePathNames[0]);
            foreach (int id in recorder.SupportedFeaturePages)
                Console.WriteLine("    0x{0:X2}", id);
        }
    }
}
```

ここで表示される値は`imapi2.h`に[`IMAPI_FEATURE_PAGE_TYPE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imapi2/ne-imapi2-imapi_feature_page_type)として定義されています。